# How can I create a datagrid inside a datatemplate of CrossHairLabelPatternTemplate?

Tags: c#, mvvm, charts, devexpress

I'm using Devexpress ChartControl and I'm trying to show a table in the crosshairlabelpattern instead of pattern that usally have metrics ( max , min and X value ) , to achieve my goal , I will need to create a datagrid inside the CrossHairLabelTemplate and Value ( X , Y ) , Max and Min columns and bind this datagrid to values that are in MVVM.

My problem is how can I create this datagrid inside the datatemplate and how can I get the values separated from the pattern?

This is an example from Devexpress WPF documentation , what I need is to override this datatemplate ( is already overrided ) and create a datagrid inside it

**View Model :**

```
public string CrossLabelPattern {get;set;}

// other code ...

CrossLabelPattern = "Avg: {{Avg}} , Max {{Max}} , Min {{Min}}";
```

**Xaml Code :**

```
<dxc:ChartControl>
        <!--#region CrosshairOptions-->
        <dxc:ChartControl.CrosshairOptions>
            <dxc:CrosshairOptions ShowArgumentLine="True" 
                                  ShowValueLabels="True" ShowValueLine="True" 
                                  ShowCrosshairLabels="True" ShowArgumentLabels="True" />
        </dxc:ChartControl.CrosshairOptions>
        <!--#endregion CrosshairOptions-->
        <dxc:XYDiagram2D CrossHairLabelPattern="{Binding CrossLabelPattern,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <dxc:BarSideBySideSeries2D ColorEach="True">
                <dxc:BarSideBySideSeries2D.Points>
                    <dxc:SeriesPoint Argument="A" Value="2" />
                    <dxc:SeriesPoint Argument="B" Value="3" />
                    <dxc:SeriesPoint Argument="C" Value="5" />
                    <dxc:SeriesPoint Argument="D" Value="7" />
                </dxc:BarSideBySideSeries2D.Points>                   
                <dxc:BarSideBySideSeries2D.CrosshairLabelTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate > <!-- create a datagrid here -->
                        <Grid>
                            <Border BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="9" >
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="AliceBlue" />
                                </Border.Background>
                                <Label BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Brown" FontStyle="Italic" 
                                       Content="{Binding Path=Text}" Padding="5,1,5,1.5" 
                                       Foreground="Red" FontSize="14"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxc:BarSideBySideSeries2D.CrosshairLabelTemplate>                 
            </dxc:BarSideBySideSeries2D>
        </dxc:XYDiagram2D>
    </dxc:ChartControl>`
```

[image: An example of what I need]